# Dynamically creating a 2 dimensional array of pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to create 2 dimensional array of pointers in c

some code

```
typedef void* element;
..
..
..
//reading n,m from user
//creating the element matrix
element** newMat = (element**)malloc(sizeof(element)*n*m)
```

and hoping to get something that will work in

```
newMat[5][3];
```

i know this syntax wont work, any idea what can work?
the best thing i got working is an array for each row, but im looking for something cleaner

Comment: Duplicate yes.... you will find your answer there.

Comment: you right got my ans there, where to upvote haccks? :)

Comment: Just up-vote the correct answer on the original answer. You cannot up-vote haccks for marking as duplicate.... it's the way SO works, and is moderated.